# Почему происходит сбрасывание формы

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Форма:

```
<section id="callback_header_js" class="form_holder clear form_holder_js">
   <form id="header_form" action="/include_areas/ajax_sms_form.php" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input required="" class="itext input_mask_js" value="" name="BIG_NUMBER">
   <button class="isubmit" type="submit">Перезвоните</button>
   </form>
</section>
```

Скрипт:

```
   $(".input_mask_js").mask("+7(999)9999999");
   $('#callback_header_js').on('submit', '#header_form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
        var m_data=$(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: m_method,
            url: '/include_areas/ajax_sms_form.php',
            data: m_data,
                success: function(result){
                    $('.form_holder_js').addClass('display_none');
                    $('.text_result_js').addClass('display_block');
                }
        });
   });
```

Форма отправляет номер телефона, и вот если номер введен не полностью, форма не отправляется, но почему-то инпут становится пустым.

Как не обнулять поле при неправильно введенном значение, а выводить алерт с ошибкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$(".input_mask_js").mask("+7(999)9999999");
$('#callback_header_js').on('submit', '#header_form', function(e) {
    if (!$(".input_mask_js").mask()) return false;

    var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
    var m_data=$(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: m_method,
        url: '/include_areas/ajax_sms_form.php',
        data: m_data,
        success: function(result){
            $('.form_holder_js').addClass('display_none');
            $('.text_result_js').addClass('display_block');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: все равно сбрасывает значение формы
Посмотрите, форма в шапке http://goo.gl/ZdfiSs

Comment: у вас на input blur который, видимо все стирает.

[а теперь немного рекламы расширения chrome, показывающего jquery events в дебагере DOM](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi)